# Search vectors in returned iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, iterator, find

Context:
I perform a std::find with a std::string on a <-string,vector->map. It then returns me an iterator of vectors, I keep the returned iterator in a const-iterator.

Problem:
I now want to iterate through the returned const-iterator, and string compare every vector at index 0. so something like:

```
while (iterator != map.end())
    if ( myStr == iterator.at(0) )
        break;
    else
        iterator++
```

That approach works just fine for me, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this, am I missing something?

Thanks for your help with this =]

Comment: If it works and it's fine with you I don't see the problem. Looks fine to me too.

Comment: yeah it works, but i was wondering if theres any stl magic i could use, to make it better.

Comment: I don't think so, but in any case why would STL magic make it better? If you mean what I think you mean by STL magic it's over used anyway. I mean you could use std::find_if (or something) but why bother. Just makes the code more complex and less easy to understand (that's personal opinion of course).

Comment: I suppose you're right, in anyway it'd have to be a linear search. I was just wondering if I could pass a functor to a search algorithm. But I didnt find anything as such =[

Comment: I think you could pass a functor to a search algorithm. The question is whether that would be an improvement. In my opinion, no, but others would disagree.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the find_if examples. In the end I went with the original code as it was easiest to read. Thanks again for your ideas, it will come to use in future I'm sure =]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of explicitly coding the search you could use [`std::find_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vstring
    {
        { "no",   "yes"   },
        { "help", "yes"   },
        { "true", "false" }
    };

const std::string myStr = "help";
auto f = std::find_if(vstring.begin(), vstring.end(),
            [&](std::vector<std::string>const & vs)
            {
                return !vs.empty() && myStr == vs[0];
            });


if (f != vstring.end())
{
    // Found.
}
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/nkI7fk .

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this more "elegant" would be something like this:

```
// C++11 allows `using` to be used instead of `typedef`
using map_type = std::map<std::string, std::vector<some_type>>;

// First find the starting point of our secondary search
const auto itr = map.find(some_string);

// Do secondary search
const auto found = std::find_if(itr, map.end(),
                                [](const map_type::value_type& pair)
                                {
                                    return (!pair.second.empty() &&
                                            pair.second[0] == myStr);
                                });
if (found != map.end())
{
    // Found the item
}
```

Comment: What am I missing, why are you searching from the found element to the end of the map?

Comment: @Dave Well that's what the OP seem to be doing.

Answer (score -2):

There is a very poor way I can imagine. It's not ordinary and should(or even must) never be used. Overloade comparison operator for vector, so it would compare only 0 positions. And then use map::find() method. Just fun.